# Read-Only Windows Forms combo-box

Tags: .net, winforms, combobox

Is there a way to make a windows forms combo-box read-only?
To be specific: the user should be able to type, but only those values within the box should be allowed (using auto-complete or a select from the list).

Or is the only way to use the validating event?

Regards

Mario

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the DropDownStyle to DropDownList, but that does not really allow typing (but it does allow selecting with the keyboard).

If you do want the user to be able to type/see incomplete words, you will have to use an event. The Validating event would be the best choice.

Comment: Thanks! I just wanted I could do without coding it myself... Guess another library component for my set...

Answer (score 3):

If you set `AutoCompleteMode = SuggestAppend` and `AutoCompleteSource = ListItems` when a user type something, automatically the combobox show entries that starts with the typed characters.

Then by handling `SelectedIndexChanged` or `SelectedValueChanged` events, you will able to intercept when a user type exactly a value present in the values list.

If you also absolutely don't want user to type anything that's not in the list, well yes, you have to handle for example `KeyDown` event like:

```
private void comboBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    char ch = (char)e.KeyValue;
    if (!char.IsControl(ch))
    {
        string newTxt = this.comboBox1.Text + ch;
        bool found = false;
        foreach (var item in this.comboBox1.Items)
        {
            string itemString = item.ToString();
            if (itemString.StartsWith(newTxt, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found)
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid I had to do that!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. the above method works for me except the KeyDown event code. Because the combobox is attached to a DataTable. Try the below code if combobox is attached to a DataTable and If you also absolutely don't want user to type anything that's not in the list.

```
private void cmbCountry_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        char ch = (char)e.KeyValue;
        if (!char.IsControl(ch))
        {
            string newTxt = this.cmbCountry.Text + ch;
            bool found = false;
            foreach (var item in cmbCountry.Items)
            {
                DataRowView row = item as DataRowView;
                if (row != null)
                {
                    string itemString = row.Row.ItemArray[0].ToString();
                    if (itemString.StartsWith(newTxt,     StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        found = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else
                    e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
            }
            if (!found)
                e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        }
    }
```